# Blue screen on normal boot and horizontal lines on safe mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

I recently turned on my computer and after 30 mins my computer froze and so I restarted it.

After that happened whenever I turn on my computer and try to boot it in normal mode the blue screen appears for a few seconds and then the computer restarts itself.

I can boot windows on safe mode and it boots normally but with the difference that I have red (pink) parallel lines all over my screen.

What could be causing this?

I have windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red/pink lines in safe mode suggest a possible graphics card problem.  If the graphics card is failing somehow then it could well cause the problems you are seeing.

As Windows starts up normally it would load the graphics card drivers which would then tell the card to use a higher power mode which might be causing the card to fall over.  Safe mode uses much lower power modes which don't use any of the advanced features of the graphics card so may be working slightly better.  Pink lines to me suggests some failure in the communications between the Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) and memory on the card or the GPU and actual display output.

A first thing to try would be to open the computer and check that the graphics card power connector is fitted and that the graphics card is well seated in its slot.

If you have one available try replacing the graphics card with another one.

Comment: Could be main-board problem ?

Comment: It *could* be a problem with the motherboard or CPU communicating with the graphics card (which is why I mentioned checking it has power and that it is fitted properly) but my "gut feeling" from what you have said would make me look at the graphics card itself first.  Are you able to take a photo of the bluescreen for us to see what is crashing?

Comment: If you have "integrated" Intel graphics then yes, this is a mainboard problem as the graphics card it built onto the mainboard.  Otherwise if you have Nvidia or AMD graphics then you need to check the graphics card itself.

Comment: motherboard: Biostar TA7900x 128M (which has separable on board graphic card)| graphic card: nvidia geforce XFX 9800 GT DDR3 |CPU: AMD Phenome 9950 Quad-Core 2.60 GHz.

Comment: I separated the graphic card and installed the (default motherboard's ATI card (shadow card)). and everything seems to be fine.(no red lines (except resuloation)). but
my monitor has 2 kind of cable which can connect to monitor 1.DVI-DVI 2.DVI-SVGA.
and my mainboard supports 2 kinds of input ports itself (DVI and SVGA).
I forced to changed the cable number 1 to the cable number 2 when i changed the graphic card (shadow card). what do you think about this? :( (sry for bad english)

Comment: I'd be incredibly surprised if it were the cable connection  type that caused your problem. The crashes suggest a hardware fault, and if your onboard graphics are fine then I still think that your old graphics card got damaged somehow  but your motherboard is fine. I can't really see how a monitor connected via dvi would be causing the crashes you had.

Comment: I will test my old graphic card on another computer and tell you the result. thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Probable causes:

1. Display drivers
2. Graphic Card failure